# Styling error of bootstrap navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm using a bootstrap template which was created by respondcms. Everything look fine on desktops, but on mobile devices the collapsed navigation is not accessible. The entries within the dropdown are not clickable.

I already tried a lot of settings, but everything looks quite similar to the example on http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

Does anyone have a clue for me? The site is accessible on http://cms.h2516034.stratoserver.net/sites/zbv/index

Thanks in advance

Raman

Comment: Just to clarify: it's not working on actual mobiles, but does work on a desktop where the browser is scaled down to mobile size? Because I don't have a smartphone handy but the mobile size functions properly. Please past your html code so we can look for problems.

Comment: No. It even doesn't work on desktops where the browser is scaled down to mobile size. It's just correct on browsers which are maximized (on desktops).

Comment: Well that is confusing because that link is working on my computer. I am using google chrome

Comment: @CZorio Try to click the submenu items (Aktivitäten - Brotbacken)

Comment: I see. Well show us your code, so we can look for errors. I could paste working versions of bootstrap collapsible navbars that work, but that's no different then looking at the demo. This is probably a code error so show please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem has to do with z-index or something. You can test in your menu point "Aktivitäten". Scale your Browser small and you will see, that the entries under the "Kontakt" entry are accessible. Maybe a rendering problem from the CMS you use?

Possible solution: (not tested global)

```
body .navbar ul.dropdown-menu li, body .navbar ul.dropdown-menu li a {
height: 30px !important;
line-height: 30px !important;
position: relative;
z-index: 100000;
}
```

respond.min.css

Comment: this is not a comment @Leothelion

Comment: Thanks CHN-mk. That looks quite good but not exactly like the example of bootstrap.
If I expand "Aktivitäten" the next following top-level items should still be visible (see: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) 
So it may be a problem with display and/or position...?

Comment: Your html code is not exactly what is in the example code by bootstrap itself. Like a said i think it could be an render problem within your CMS. See https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar for the original example code. Also i don't know if the problem may is caused by missing container classes. @Raman

Answer (score 0):

@Raman try this. It should work

```
<style>
@media(max-width:767px){
    body .navbar li {
        height: auto;
        line-height: 65px;
    }
}
</style>
```